# Вкладки при открытии проекта VS

Tags: visual-studio, интерфейс, редактор, вкладки, visual-studio-2019

Раньше при очередном открытии проекта в VisualStudio 2019 открывались вкладки, которые были открыты при последнем сохранении проекта.
Но сейчас (случился баг или ещё что-то) при открытии проекта, открываются 4 определённые вкладки (однажды и сохранял-закрывал с ними). Но сейчас они мне не требуются и каждый раз их закрывать и открывать нужные уже надоело.
Как VS понимает, какие вкладки открывать при запуске? Есть какой-то файл-конфиг? Или как ещё можно это проблему решить?

Comment: В папке солюшена есть скрытая папка .vs. Внутри неё есть скрытый файл .suo. В нём хранятся открытые вкладки. Возможно, есть смысл удалить этот файл, после чего всё заработает как надо. Естественно, файл создастся заново.

Comment: Возможно, вас заинтересует расширение для Студии [Workspace Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreyVeselov.WorkspaceManager). Есть и другие с подобным функционалом.